# Where can I find ready-made Android Studio GUIs to copy&paste?

Tags: android, user-interface, templates, android-studio, interface

I started with Android Studio and  would like to get started.
I do not like fiddling around with GUIs and would like to play lego with ready-made pages and common standard interfaces.

Where can I find Android GUI XMLs to copy&paste or download to get started?

Does anyone know a good Android resource site, something like templatemonster for Android GUIs?

For example I need:

- a settings page with switches, range sliders and a couple of fields, nicely arranged and already profesionallly looking
- a user profile page
- an inbox/outbox
- a speech bubble view
- list/grid view with images
- a login/signup/lost password menu

Comment: I min I'm making answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use library for GUI and many other purpose the best place is [Android assets studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/)

And there is a page that haves tricks for GUI is [Android cheat sheet](http://petrnohejl.github.io/Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers/)

And [Android assets studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) for images

If you get stuck visit Android's [official site](http://developer.android.com)

Grabbed by JRummy's Blog